# Automatic adjustment of form width with textarea witdh in HTML

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a problem concerning the width of my form.
To understand it better, please look at the following two images.
[image: Screenshot 1 Text area Width and Form Width is ok]
[image: Screenshot 2 Text area Width and Form Width is not ok]

I would like to adjust the length of my form with the length of my text area, so that the width of the text area is not longer than the form (see also screenshot 2). Could you please show me how can I do that? I tried to set the width of the text area on auto (like height) but with width it doesn't work.
In the following you can see my code:

```
<form role="form" class="row-fluid hide comment popover">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Comments on Test</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="comment_text" form="comment" name="text" placeholder="There is no comment yet"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="btn btn-default" type='button' value='Submit Comment' onClick='updateComment("@module",this.parentElement)' />
</div>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Greets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `max-width` to form element and enable only partial width changing:

```
<form>
    <textarea></textarea>
</form>

<script>
    form {background: grey; width: 400px; padding: 20px;}
    textarea {padding:0; background: blue; width: 200px; height: 100px; max-width: 400px;}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y0gp8dtx/

OR

set `min-width` to `form` element and add `display: inline-block` or `float: left` to prevent default `width: 100%`

```
form {background: grey; min-width: 400px; padding: 20px; display: inline-block;}
textarea {padding:0; background: blue; width: 200px; height: 100px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y0gp8dtx/2/